# Using 64 bit machine, core i7 5500u, ubuntu 14.04 LTS shows only 2 cores

Tags: 14.04

I recently bought a HP ProBook 430 G2 with core i7 5500u processor. I upgraded the 4 GB RAM to 8 GB. In windows 4 cores are being shown however when I type

```
sudo dmidecode
```

I am shown this : Core Count: 2, Core Enabled 2, Thread Count 2

Is there any way I can use all the cores ?

Comment: what do you get from `$ cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Answer (score 3):

Your CPU the [Intel Core i7 5500U](http://ark.intel.com/products/85214/Intel-Core-i7-5500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz) has 2 cores 4 threads by design.

The number of threads also are referred to as "virtual cores".

To see that your CPU performs hyperthreading see `ht` in the `flags` section from `dmidecode`. To work appropriately it needs to be set to `enabled` in your BIOS.

Comment: @shankha benerjee Please see my answer here for an explanation of core vs threads http://askubuntu.com/questions/668538/cores-vs-threads-how-many-threads-should-i-run-on-this-machine/668542#668542